# What's the best way, in this situation, to structure and action/generate two different emails from one form submit button via PHP Mailer?

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

Educate me :)

I have a simple HTML form consisting of 3 fields: name, email and message.

I have created below some PHP code which will act as an auto-responder to the email address entered into the form containing a fixed message and an attachment.

I wish for a second email to be sent out to a fixed email address to a company which will only contain the name, email and message entered into the form.

```
<?php

  $field_fullname = $_POST['cf_mercury']; // cf_name is a convention used by the HTML form
  $field_email = $_POST['cf_jupiter'];
  $field_message = $_POST['cf_uranus'];

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body = $field_message;

$mail->SetFrom("company@address.co.uk", "ETAP Centre"); 

$mail->AddReplyTo("company@address.co.uk", "ETAP Centre");

$address = "email@address.co.uk";
$mail->AddAddress($field_email, $field_fullname);

$mail->Subject    = 'Auto Response: Message from the ETAP Centre';

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment(""); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send your email to company@address.co.uk');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
} else {
  ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for contacting the ETAP Centre. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Any and all help would be hugely appreciated and if I can do anything more to articulate my question and increase its understandability just let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$field_fullname = $_POST['cf_mercury']; // cf_name is a convention used by the HTML form
$field_email = $_POST['cf_jupiter'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_uranus'];

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body = "Message";

$mail->SetFrom('company@address.co.uk', 'ETAP Centre'); 

$mail->AddReplyTo('company@address.co.uk', 'ETAP Centre');

$address = $field_email;
$mail->AddAddress($address, $field_fullname);

$mail->Subject    = 'Auto-Response: Thank you for contacting the ETAP Centre, '.$field_fullname;

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";     // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("/websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/da/mt/ec/damtechdesigns.co.uk/public_html/proofs/etap/etapbooklet.pdf");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment(""); // attachment
$mail->Send();
```

// E-Mail to Company

```
 $mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

 $body = $field_message;

 $mail->SetFrom($field_email, $field_fullname); 

 $mail->AddReplyTo($field_email,$field_fullname);

 $address = "company@address.co.uk";
 $mail->AddAddress($address, "ETAP Centre");

 $mail->Subject    = 'Message via the ETAP Centre website from '.$field_fullname;

 $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

 $mail->MsgHTML($body);

 $mail->AddAttachment(""); // attachment
 $mail->AddAttachment(""); // attachment
 $sent = $mail->Send();
 if($sent)
 {
  header("location:yoururl");
 }
 else
 {
  header("location:yoururl");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated my question. Unfortunately, your suggestion seems to have no effect. Do I need two different phpmailers? or can I action to separate scripts?

Comment: I personally would use two separate objects I would do $personmail-> and $companymail-> if that does not work then i would try by just sending a blank email and adding back properties gradually.

Comment: cracked it just needed a names changing to $mail2 on the second email and $mail2 = clone $mail; adding

Comment: just a side note you may want to add some validation to $field_fullname $field_email $field_message as currently I believe your form can be used as a mail multiple people through entering my.mail@mail.com;my.mailtwo@mail.com etc. into your form

Comment: Ohh right I had no idea. What would you recommend? I am new to this you see.

Comment: You should check ALL user input to ensure that what you expect to be in the field is what is in the field. So in this case ensure that the email being entered is a valid email and does not have chars such as a ; in it.

Comment: Oh I'm with you. I have that in the HTML but would I need to include validation in the PHP too?

Comment: yes, because I can copy your html page, strip out the validation and point it to use your php page for processing and post what I want through.

Comment: Aww cheers @Nicholas King I will look into it and when I get 15 rep I will throw you some points. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just repeat the block that starts with `$mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"` with the Company email address as the recipient before your `Message Failed` if statement. and just include the fields you want to send (i.e. name, email and message).

Alternatively, if you'd like, you can send a copy of the same exact email by adding the Company email address as a `BCC` on the email, by adding `$mail->AddBCC`

Comment: Thanks for the help I have followed your advice but it seems to be ignoring the second email and not sending at at all. I will update my question so you can see what code I am using

Comment: you need two mail objects or use $mail->send(); after the first then $mail->send(); after the second

Answer (score 1):

The answer was achieved by changing the variable `$mail` in the second email to `$mail2` and adding `mail2 = clone $mail;`. This allows the user full control over the two emails with optional attachments in both as well as using variables captured by the form in either email. Thanks for your help! :)

```
<?php

      $field_fullname = $_POST['cf_mercury']; // cf_name is a convention used by the HTML form
      $field_email = $_POST['cf_jupiter'];
      $field_message = $_POST['cf_uranus'];

    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

    // E-Mail to Client

    $mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

    $body = "Thank you for contacting the whoever";

    $mail->SetFrom('company@address.co.uk', 'Enter Sender Name'); 

    $mail->AddReplyTo('company@address.co.uk', 'Enter Sender Name');

    $address = $field_email;
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $field_fullname);

    $mail->Subject    = 'Auto-Response: Thank you for contacting the ETAP Centre, '.$field_fullname;

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->AddAttachment("");      // attachment
    $mail->AddAttachment(""); // attachment

    $sent = $mail->Send();


    // E-Mail to Company

    $mail2 = clone $mail;

    $mail2             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

    $body = $field_message;

    $mail2->SetFrom($field_email, $field_fullname); 

    $mail2->AddReplyTo($field_email, $field_fullname);

    $address = "company@address.co.uk";
    $mail2->AddAddress($address, "Enter Recipient Name");

    $mail2->Subject    = 'Message via the NAME website from '.$field_fullname;

    $mail2->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail2->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail2->AddAttachment(""); // attachment - leave incase they are needed in the future
    $mail2->AddAttachment(""); // attachment

    $sent = $mail2->Send();

    if($mail_status) {
      { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('fail');
            window.location = 'index.html';
        </script>
<?php
    }
    } else {
      ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('success');
            window.location = 'index.html';
        </script>
<?php
    }
    ?>
```